# Wait_For_Component is not working in cogs [discord-py-slash-commands-components]

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to send a button in cogs with the discord-py-slash-commands lib but the problem is the `wait_for_component` is not working and i didn't get any errors in console but if i click on the button it shows me that Interaction Failed! and here is my cog file

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash.context import ComponentContext
from discord_slash.model import ButtonStyle
from discord_slash.utils.manage_components import create_actionrow, create_button, wait_for_component

class buttons(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @commands.command()
    async def button(self, ctx):
        btns = [create_button(
                    style=ButtonStyle.green,
                    label="Button!"
                )]
        action_row = create_actionrow(*btns)
        await ctx.send("My Message", components=[action_row])
        button_ctx: ComponentContext = await wait_for_component(self.client,components=actionrow)
        await button_ctx.edit_origin(content="You pressed a button!")
        
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(buttons(client))
```